# Get index and value of variadic template at compile time

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, libpqxx

I have a function that looks like this

```cpp
template <typename... Rets, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Rets...> call_nn(std::string_view query, Args... args)
{
  pqxx::work w(con_);
  pqxx::row res = w.exec_params1(pqxx::zview(query), args...);
  w.commit();
  return // std::tuple<Rets...>((res[std::index_sequence_for<Rets>{}].as<Rets>())...); doesn't work
}
```

`pqxx::row` represents one row of result table from postgres. It supports getting column value as `res[0].as<int>()`.

The problem is that I don't know how to expand the variadic template argument to access the type index and the type itself. What should I put instead of `???`?

```cpp
return std::tuple(ret[/*???*/].as<Rets>()...);
```

I tried to define `int i = 0` and expand like `res[i++].as<Rets>()...` but then compiler gives warning

```
Multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i'
```

so maybe there are some better ways to expand return statement to something like example below without runtime variables

```cpp
return std::tuple(ret[0].as<X>(), ret[1].as<Y>(), /*...*/ ret[n].as<Z>() );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to create a second parameter pack for the values in `index_sequence`:

```cpp
template <typename... Rets, std::size_t... Idxs, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Rets...> call_nn(std::index_sequence<Idxs...>, std::string_view query, Args&... args)
{
  pqxx::work w(con_);
  pqxx::row res = w.exec_params1(pqxx::zview(query), args...);
  w.commit();
  return std::tuple<Rets...>((res[Idxs].as<Rets>())...);
}

template <typename... Rets, typename... Args>
std::tuple<Rets...> call_nn(std::string_view query, Args... args)
{
    return call_nn<Rets...>(std::index_sequence_for<Rets...>{}, query, args...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++20, lambda expressions can have an explicit template parameter list. Calling a lambda immediately after definition has become a pervasive modern idiom. Combination of the two ideas is very common in variadic template programming. But the primary rule - as ever - is that all parameter packs in a pack expansion expression are expanded together and are required to have the same size:

```
return [&res] <std::size_t ... i>
       (std::index_sequence<i...>) {
       return std::tuple{ res[i].as<Rets>()... };
} (std::index_sequence_for<Rets...>{});
```

Notice that in the inner return statement, `i` and `Rets` are expanded simultaneously.

In the above code I have used the C++20 CTAD syntax to shorten the code sequence a bit; that's why `tuple` is not followed by `<Rets...>`. Explicit argument list in such cases is normally used for conversions, or when class arguments can't be totally deduced from constructor parameters.